# PHP Gearman tasks not returning jobHandle

Tags: php, gearman

We're using Gearman and when do use methods like doLowBackground or doHigh, these all return a jobHandle, but when we do [tasks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmantask.jobhandle.php) there is no jobHandle object.  We get the GearmanTask object, instead of getting the jobHandle, we get `string(0) ""`

Any ideas what could cause this?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the code and additional info:

```
// $client = \GearmanClient; // servers added, all that jazz
// $workload = 'string';

$arguments = array(
    'handleJob',
    $workload
);

$task = call_user_func_array(array($client, $method), $arguments);
            
if ($task instanceof GearmanTask) {
    $handles[] = $task->jobHandle();
}

$data = $client->runTasks();
```

The tasks run correctly but `$handle` is being populated with empty strings (one for each task added)

EDIT: This is the response we get:

```
object(GearmanTask)#294 (0) {
}
```

I've dumped every PECL gearman object, nothing ever displays, here's the client, populated with servers, options, etc

```
object(GearmanClient)#291 (0) {
}
```

Doesn't show anything.

Comment: Just updated with the code example, thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `method` ?

Comment: Any of the `addTask` methods - `addTask`, `addTaskHigh`, etc.

Comment: I guess that the `jobHandle` will be available not before you've called `runTasks()`

Comment: Nope, even after $client->runTasks(); is called, the tasks still return an empty string when calling jobHandle() on each task.  We're using PELC Gearman

Comment: can you add the output of `var_dump($task)` to your question? right after creation

Comment: Weird question: can you see the jobs in the gearman server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A job handle is not assigned to a task until the task is received and queued by the Gearman job server.

However, you can use [GearmanClient::setCreatedCallback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.setcreatedcallback.php) to get the handle once it has been queued. This must be done before both adding and running the tasks:

```
$client = new \GearmanClient();
$client->addServer('127.0.0.1');
$handles = array();

$client->setCreatedCallback(function (\GearmanTask $task) use (&$handles) {
    $handles[] = $task->jobHandle();
});

$client->addTask('functionName', 'workload'); // ...
$client->runTasks();
```